# How to pretty print xml with jackson/woodstox?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jackson, woodstox

I have a xml input stream that contains all tags in one line, eg `<xml><MyRequest><someProperty attribute="test"/></MyRequest></xml>`

Question: how can I best output this *pretty printed*?

Using `jackson` and `woodstox`, it would be as follows if I had a simple java bean object:

```
ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(new MyRequest());
```

But I don't have any java bean and don't want to create one. Just pretty print the given xml without transformation to any bean.

How could I best achieve this, with regards to performance?

Comment: `xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);` , but it's kinda obvious. Do you want something to control pretty print format?

Comment: Well and how can I then convert the existing `String xml = <xml><MyRequest><someProperty attribute="test"/></MyRequest></xml>` to an *indented* string? As written, I don't have a java object to parse, just a oneliner string that contains the xml I want to format.

Comment: you still need to parse your string somehow. Easy option is like this: `xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(xmlMapper.readTree(xmlString))` but i think  custom pojo can outperforme it by 30-50%

Comment: also: if ALL you want to do is to indent an XML input/String (... although, why?), Jackson may be overkill. I think there are other libs that can do this one task (with usual caveats that white space in XML may have meaning and automatic indentation can change meaning for some inputs -- but I assume not in your case)

Comment: @SlaxMan + 1 and btw @membersound there is default java parsers you can use `javax.xml.*`. More boilerplate code but much more flexible. Something like this https://github.com/varren/JavaFXWebViewPrettyXML/blob/master/src/main/java/sample/XmlWebViewHelper.java#L97-L115 (probably you can find better demos, i just used it for one old project)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by setting this property:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
String reqXml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(new MyRequest());
```